# Batch 'IF' command not working

Tags: batch-file

this code just skip "if" commend and go to another 
i wont to see somethink like that:
"2 2 end" or "3 3 end", but it shows only "3 1 end" or "2 1 end". Please help im new in this.

```
@echo off
set /p number=
if %number%=="1" goto 1
if %number%=="2" goto 2
if %number%=="3" goto 3
:1
echo 1
goto end
:2
echo 2
goto end 
:3
echo 3
goto end
:end
echo end
pause
```

Comment: Remove the quotes or enclose your variable with the quotes. (The `if` comparison is literal and exact.)

Answer (score 2):

The `IF` command in batch is purely a string comparison, not a numeric one. Moreover, quotation marks *are* significant. Your code contains lines such as

```
if %number%=="1" goto 1
```

which compares the value of the variable `number` with the string `"1"`. However, your `SET` statement implicitly wants you to type `1` or `2` or `3`, with no quotes.

In order to avoid a syntax error if the user provides a blank or a null string as the response to the `SET` prompt, you want to quote `%number%`:

```
if "%number%"=="1" goto 1
```

Additionally, you want to put an unconditional goto before the label `:1` to protect that subroutine; if you don't, then if the user doesn't enter `1`, `2`, or `3`, option 1 will be executed because of fall-through.

It is also possible - I'm not quite clear on how it works myself - that you may want to use delayed expansion, which would require you to change the `IF`s to use `!` instead of `%`:

```
if "!number!"=="1" goto 1
```

There is a very good reference site for batch at [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/); you may want to pay special attention to [Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and the [`IF` command](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html).